# Cgroups Memory Limits - Script gets killed well before limit is reached

Tags: cgroup

I am trying out a simple example to understand how to limit the memory consumption of processes.

I have created a test memory group, set the limits for both memory.limit_in_bytes and memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes to 5 MB.

I have a really simple program that allocates memory in increments of 1 MB (by reading from a random device).

I would have expected my script to reach somewhere close to 5 MB before it gets killed, but it gets killed right after it reads 1 MB.

When I raise the cgroup limits to 8 MB, it gets killed after consuming 3 MB.

I have tried with different limits, and have noticed it consistently gets killed before reaching half of the allocated limit.

Can someone please let me know if I am missing anything else?

Would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Note that you don't have to read from a device to allocate memory.  It is sufficient to use malloc and touch a byte in each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cgroups memory limits also cover executable code for the program, including the executable itself and any shared libraries it needs.  You can use tools like `ps` and `top` (or one of the top variants) to watch actual memory use before you set limits with cgroups, and possibly before you allow your test program to start allocating memory.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected the libraries the program uses, and as you suggested, that seems to be the case.  I also used pmap to verify the actual memory consumed, and that validates your answer here.